# Using syslog from a kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, syslog

I am writing a linux kernel module to report statistics and send some log messages. Can I use syslog to accomplish this job? Or is `printk` the only way?

Answer (score 5):

The messages written via `printk` with the right level end up in syslog anyway (in normal configurations).

However, if you have a *really* strange setup and you *really* want to use the user-space syslog from kernel space, you should use the usual suspects (`sys_open`, `sys_write`, `sys_close`) on the `/dev/log` socket, because [this is what syslogd is listening to](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/glibc/html_chapter/libc_18.html#SEC382).

EDIT: By `sys_open`, `sys_open`, `sys_write`, `sys_close` I meant the *system calls implementations* of the kernel and **not** some functions from userspace (syslog.h or whatever).

Comment: Yes, I tried to use sys_open, sys_write and sys_close from syslog.h. But learnt that one cannot use user level library functions (syslog.h) from kernel modules. So, it looks like printk is my only choice for now unless if I can find a way to hack printk to send messages with different facility other than KERNEL. Thanks for your help tough :)